# How to I wire my new awning motor to the the box outside?

Tags: electrical

I don't know anything about awnings or electrical wiring. My awning that was controlled by a switch has stopped working. So, I hired a handy man that came out and took apart the awning (wiring and motor). He is no where to be found now.

I have ordered the replacement motor. The difference between the old motor and the new one is that the new one also came with a remote.

I was able to resemble the awning and anchored it back up.

Problem I am having is I don't know which wires I need to connect from the awning motor to the wires coming out from the exterior electrical box. The awning motor has 5 wires in total and are labelled as follow on the manual:

- Blue - neutral
- Brown - live wire
- Green/yellow - earth
- 2 white wires - control

The box has 4 wires

- Brown
- Pink
- Black
- White

Comment: Knowing where in the world you are would be very helpful! For example, in the US, the Brown & Pink wires would be somewhat unexpected unless your wiring was run in conduit (in which case it's quite reasonable). Pictures of the awning hook-up box _and_ the switch that currently controls it (pull the switch out of the box but do **not** disconnect any of the wiring!) would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Would contact the makers of the awning.  They should know best how to wire the new motor.

Comment: Can you post photos of the nameplate label on the motor and of the wiring box on the wall please?